# Asp.net web.config syntax issue

Tags: asp.net, web-config, web-application-security

I am working on asp.net application for removing security vulnerabilities. The vulnerability which I want to discuss are '**X-XSS Protection**' and '**clickjacking**'.
I went through searching and followed this **[link](https://www.insiderattack.net/2014/04/configuring-secure-iis-response-headers.html)**. I just used the solution under the head '***Using `<customHeaders>` in Web.Config***'

After this when I run the application I got 500 internal server error: `HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error`. In the `detailed error information` under `Config Error` label it says that `Unrecognized element 'add'`.

After this I removed the closing tags `</add>` and just left with `<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY"/>` and now the application runs properly.

On following points I need some help:

1. Why the syntax given in above link does not work?
2. Can anyone explain the significance of below lines:

> `<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY"/> <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block"/> <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff "/>`

Little bit I know that these are additional security headers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with the format in the linked article, which I've replicated here...

```
<httpprotocol> 
 <customheaders> 
  <remove name="X-Powered-By"> 
  <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY"> 
  <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block"> 
  <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff "> 
 </add></add></add></remove></customheaders> 
</httpprotocol>
```

- `<httpprotocol>` and `</httpprotocol>` must be `<httpProtocol>` and `</httpProtocol>`
- `<customheaders>` and `</customheaders>` must be `<customHeaders>` and `</customHeaders>`
- `<add>` and `<remove>` must be direct children of `<customHeaders>`... they cannot be nested.
- although I can't say 100%, I believe the space in `"nosiff "` might be an issue (although it will probably be handled correctly, I would suggest it was removed in case a browser ignores it)

The use of `<add></add>` or `<add/>` elements makes no difference, as long as they're all direct children of the `<customHeaders>` element

```
<httpProtocol> 
 <customHeaders> 
  <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
  <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
  <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
  <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
 </customHeaders> 
</httpProtocol>
```

For the actual options see...

- [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)
- [X-XSS-Protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection)
- [X-Content-Type-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options)